# Array of Objects to an Array of Values for One Key

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, similar to the below:

```
const objectArray = [
  { 
    key1: 'value1a',
    key2: 'value2a',
    key3: 'value3a',
  },{ 
    key1: 'value1b',
    key2: 'value2b',
    key3: 'value3b',
  },{ 
    key1: 'value1c',
    key2: 'value2c',
    key3: 'value3c',
  },
];
```

and I would like to get an array containing all the values stored in, say, `key2`.

At the moment, my code looks as follows:

```
const valueArray = [];
objectArray.forEach((object) => {
  valueArray.push(object.key2);
});
```

This then results in

```
const valueArray = ['value2a', 'value2b', 'value2c'];
```

It feels like there is probably a more eloquent way to achieve the same thing, in just one line but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that - can someone point me towards some documentation, or example code on how to do that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const objectArray = [
    {
        key1: 'value1a',
        key2: 'value2a',
        key3: 'value3a',
    },
    {
        key1: 'value1b',
        key2: 'value2b',
        key3: 'value3b',
    },
    {
        key1: 'value1c',
        key2: 'value2c',
        key3: 'value3c',
    },
];

const result = objectArray.map(obj => obj.key2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map `objectArray`:

```js
const valueArray = objectArray.map(o => o.key2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (which creates a new array with the result of applying a callback with each element) with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter).

```js
const objectArray = [
  { 
    key1: 'value1a',
    key2: 'value2a',
    key3: 'value3a',
  },{ 
    key1: 'value1b',
    key2: 'value2b',
    key3: 'value3b',
  },{ 
    key1: 'value1c',
    key2: 'value2c',
    key3: 'value3c',
  },
];
const res = objectArray.map(({key2})=>key2);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it for any key:

```js
const objectArray = [
  {
    key1: 'value1a',
    key2: 'value2a',
    key3: 'value3a',
  }, {
    key1: 'value1b',
    key2: 'value2b',
    key3: 'value3b',
  }, {
    key1: 'value1c',
    key2: 'value2c',
    key3: 'value3c',
  },
];

function getByKey(key) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, red) => acc = [...acc, red[key]], [])
}

console.log(getByKey("key2"));
```